# multiple assertions in regex with word boundaries

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern using a word boundary. I want to match something like this
`\b(\d+)\/(\d+)\b` which matches `3/4 2/3 1/2` though I don't want to match a number next to a fraction `3 2/3` I want this to be invalid. I know I can use `^some pattern...$` so it `3 2/3` would be invalid. Although, I want to able have multiple matches in a single line that's why I am using word boundary. I would like something like `3/4 2 2/3 hello 4/5 some text` where only `3/4 4/5` are valid. How can I accomplish that with regex?

Comment: Which language or regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 2):

As you are using capturing groups already, you can match a digit followed by a fraction which you don't want to keep.

Then use an alternation, and capture the fraction part in a whole group that you want to keep.

Your value is in group 1.

```
\b\d+ +\d+\/\d+\b|\b(\d+\/\d+)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b\d+ +\d+\/\d+\b` Match 1+ digits followed by a fraction
- `|` Or capture in **group 1** Matching a fracture
- `\b(\d+\/\d+)\b`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jO9bo7/1)

---

If lookarounds with a quantifier are supported, another option is to match a fraction and assert what is directly to the left is not 1+ digit followed by a space which by itself has a whitespace boundary to the left.

```
(?<!(?<!\S)\d+ +)\b\d+\/\d+\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JrFz1n/1)

---

**Note** about using [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` as pointed out by [@CarySwoveland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256970/cary-swoveland) is that the fraction will match in `a7 3/4` and will not match in `agent:7 3/4` as there is no word boundary between `a` and `7` and there is a word boundary between `:` and `7`. See this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHM27X/1)

Comment: Good solution. (I was somehow initially thinking the fraction should be disregarded if a digit was before it even if there were intervening characters. Dumb, dumb, dumb. But I am not commenting to air my woes.) I'm not convinced there is an argument for restricting what immediately precedes one or more digits followed by a space followed by the fraction. For example, you match `"3/4"` in `"a7 3/4"` but not in `"agent:7 3/4"`. Minor: you might  replace `\d+ \d+` with `\d+ +\d+`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Good note, that is an edge case and  there might be more of those I think. The OP mentiones a word boundary, so I thought of using that. I will make a note about using word boundaries.

Comment: Thank you I definitely need to learn more about lookbehind